# How to invite others to join my world in multiplayer

Tags: craft-the-world

[Update 1.2.001](https://steamcommunity.com/app/248390/allnews/) announced a multiplayer mode to Craft the World:

> - Added a multiplayer mode [...]

**How can I group up with my friends and join each others worlds?**

I tried the Steam invite options, but none of these work. Also, I cannot seem to find an in-game option to do this.